# Python: Is it possible to use instantiation with ' ' for a custom str class?

Tags: python, string, class, oop, superclass

I wrote a custom str class, because I want to have a casefold() method that replaces German and Scandinavian umlauts (ä, å, ö, ø, ü…). It inherits from the standard str class and just supersedes the casefold() method after making use of it.

```
class str(str):
    def casefold(self):
        umlauts: dict ={
            'ä': 'ae',
            'ö': 'oe',
            'ü': 'ue',
            'œ': 'oe',
            'ø': 'oe',
            'æ': 'ae',
            'å': 'aa',
        }
        string_ = self.__repr__().casefold()
        for letter in string_:
            if letter in umlauts:
                string_ = string_.replace(letter, umlauts[letter])
        return string_
```

if I use str() to instantiate a string, it works fine:

```
str('äåöøü').casefold()
"'aeaaoeoeue'"
```

But when I instantiate with '', the standard str class is used.

```
'äåöøüß'.casefold()
'äåöøüss'

type(str('äåöøü'))
<class '__main__.str'>

type('äåöøüß')
<class 'str'>
```

Is there a way to change this, to change the instantiation with '' to the custom class? I couldn’t find anything on this.

Comment: I don't think that you can override how the interpreter parses literals.

Comment: You seem to be asking if it's possible to override the type that is created when you enter literals. And the answer is no. You cannot make it so that '' uses a type other than the built-in str type in \_\_builtins__.

You can override \_\_builtins__.str, but that will only affect explicit use of the name str.